# Other stuff on the page overlapping the navigation bar jquery.sticky

Tags: jquery, css

Good morning, I'm creating a webpage and i'm not an experienced developer. I have made a sticky navbar using the jquery plugin sticky.js. Everything was perfect but when i have added the animations to the pictures now the pictures are overlapping the navigation bar. How i can stop the overlapping of other stuff.[example](http://www.sandro.x10host.com/sarmad/try.html) Your answer will be very very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to replace `z-index: auto;` with `z-index: 1;` in the inline style of the div with `id="sticker"`

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#sticker` element is styled with `z-index: auto` by jQuery Sticky, so you will not be able to change this value anyhow except by changing the JavaScript code in the script - which is not a good idea.

An easy and quick solution would be to set a higher `z-index` value to the parent of this element, namely the `#sticker-sticky-wrapper` div.

Keep in mind that `z-index` will not do anything if the `position` of your element is `static`, which is the default one. Therefore, this is what you need to add in your CSS style sheet:

```
#sticker-sticky-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Learn more about `z-index` at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: Thank you so much Siavas. It was very helpful and you have explained it like a boss :) . Thanks again. If you have any experience of web-scraping can i ask you another favour?